# Computational Formula for Geodesic Distance on a Statistical Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, information-theory, fisher-information, information-geometry

I am working on a problem where I need to compute the geodesic distance between two points on a statistical manifold.

suppose we have two datasets $X$ and $Y$, I map them to PDF using the Kernel density estimation so now we will have two points $P(x|X)$ and $P(y|Y)$ on the statistical manifolds., I am looking to find the geodesic distance between them. I am aware of the theoretical formula for geodesic distance on a manifold:

$
d(P, Q) = \inf_{\gamma}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))} \, dt
$

where $P$ and $Q$ are points on the manifold, $\gamma: [0, 1] \rightarrow M$ is a smooth curve on the manifold $M$ connecting $P$ and $Q$, and $g_{\gamma(t)}$ is the metric tensor at $\gamma(t)$.

However, I am looking for a computational formula or algorithm that can be implemented to calculate this distance, considering the specific nature of statistical manifolds and the representation of points as PDFs.

Any insights or references to relevant literature/methods that provide a computational approach to find the geodesic distance on a statistical manifold would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Find explicit formulas for the Riemannian distance on non-obvious Riemannian manifolds is almost impossible. When there is a lot of symmetry (or group actions), we can tell what they are. But in general .... I can't imagine that in the case of a statistical manifold with random structure you'll find much to say. But I have no experience in this area.

Comment: +1 to Ted Shifrin and therefore I will ask: Can you somehow assume that your distributions belong to the exponential family or so? That might help? That seems to be one of the more common assumptions in information geometry.

Comment: Actually I have point clouds in 3D as a data so we do not know the distribution,I have used the KDE to convert them to PDF.

Comment: Imagine a manifold (even a surface) whose geodesics you understand well. Now introduce a steep mountain with small base in the neighborhood of a point. It is in some sense a “small” local blip, but think about its global ramifications on the distance function.